# Proof of injectivity of $\operatorname{Hom}(U, V) \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(U', V') \to \operatorname{Hom}(U \otimes U', V \otimes V')$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, linear-transformations

Let $U, U', V, V'$ be four vector spaces. Below I have attached a proof of the injectivity of the canonical map $$\theta: \operatorname{Hom}(U, V) \otimes \operatorname{Hom}(U', V') \to \operatorname{Hom}(U \otimes U', V \otimes V').$$ 
I'm wondering: why not make it simpler? Suppose $\theta(\sum\limits_{i=1}^r f_i \otimes g_i)=0$, where $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r f_i \otimes g_i$ is written so that $\{f_i\}$ and $\{g_i\}$ are linearly independent sets (such is possible with $r>0$ iff $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r f_i \otimes g_i \neq 0$). Then we can take a vector $u$ such that $f_1(u) \neq 0$ and $f_i(u) =0$ for $i\neq 1$, and similarly for $u'$, so that $\theta (\sum\limits_{i=1}^r f_i \otimes g_i)(u \otimes u') = f_1(u) \otimes g_1(u') \neq 0$, a contradiction.

Isn't this a valid proof? There's no problem with choosing such elements $u,u'$, is there?

---

The same argument that we used in the proof of Theorem 14.7 will work here. Namely, the map $(u,v)\mapsto \tau u \otimes \sigma v$ from $U \times V$ to $U' \otimes V'$ is bilinear in $u$ and $v$ and so there is a unique linear map $(\tau \odot \sigma):U \otimes V \to U' \otimes V'$ for which $$(\tau \odot \sigma)(u \otimes v)=\tau u \otimes \sigma v$$ The function $$\phi:\mathcal{L}(U,U') \times \mathcal{L}(V,V') \to \mathcal{L}(U \otimes V,U' \otimes V')$$ defined by $$\phi(\tau,\sigma)=\tau \odot \sigma$$ is bilinear, since \begin{align*} ((a\tau + b\mu) \odot \sigma)(u \otimes v)&=(a \tau + b \mu)(u) \otimes \sigma v\\ &=(a \tau u + b \mu u) \otimes \sigma v \\ &=a[\tau u \otimes \sigma v]+b[\mu u \otimes \sigma v]\\ &=a(\tau \odot \sigma)(u \otimes v)+b(\mu \odot \sigma)(u \otimes v)\\ &=(a(\tau \odot \sigma)+b(\mu \odot \sigma))(u \otimes v) \end{align*}and similarly for the second coordinate. Hence, there is a unique linear transformation $$\theta:\mathcal{L}(U,U')\otimes \mathcal{L}(V,V') \to \mathcal{L}(U \otimes V, U' \otimes V')$$ satisfying $$\theta(\tau \otimes \sigma)=\tau \odot \sigma$$ that is,$$[\theta(\tau \otimes \sigma)](u \otimes v)=\tau u \otimes \sigma v$$ To see that $\theta$ is injective, if $h \in \mathcal{L}(U,U')\otimes \mathcal{L}(V,V')$ is nonzero, then we may write $$h=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i$$ where the $f_i \in \mathcal{L}(U,U')$ are nonzero and the set $\{g_i\} \subseteq \mathcal{L}(V,V')$ is linearly independent. If $\theta(h)=0$, then for all $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ we have $$0=\theta(h)(u \otimes v)=\sum_{i=1}^n \theta(f_i \otimes g_i)(u \otimes v)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(u) \otimes g_j(v)$$ Since $h \neq 0$, it follows that $f_i \neq 0$ for some $i$ and so we may choose a $u \in U$ such that $f_i(u) \neq 0$ for some $i$. Moreover, we may assume, by reindexing if
necessary, that the set $\{f_1(u),\ldots,f_m(u)\}$ is a maximal linearly independent subset of $\{f_1(u),\ldots,f_n(u)\}$. Hence, for each $k>m$, we have $$f_k(u)=\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{k,i}f_i(u)$$ and so \begin{align*} 0&=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(u) \otimes g_i(v)\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(u) \otimes g_i(v) + \sum_{k=m+1}^n \left[\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{k,i} f_i(u)\right]\otimes g_k(v)\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(u) \otimes g_i(v) + \sum_{k=m+1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{k,i} [f_i(u)\otimes g_k(v)]\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(u) \otimes g_i(v) + \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(u) \otimes \left[\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_{k,i} g_k(v) \right] \\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(u) \otimes \left[g_i(v)+\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_{k,i} g_k(v)\right] \end{align*}

Thus, the linear independence of $\{f_1(u),\ldots,f_m(u)\}$ implies that for eaxch $i \leq m$,
$$g_i(v)+\sum_{k=m+1}^n\alpha_{k,i}g_k(v)=0$$
for all $v \in V$ and so
$$g_i+\sum_{k=m+1}^n\alpha_{k,i}g_k=0$$
But this contradicts the fact that the set $\{g_i\}$ is linearly independent. Hence, it cannot happen that $\theta(h) = 0$ for $h \neq 0$ and so $\theta$ is injective.

(Original pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHEHV.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejkBQ.jpg))

Comment: For what it's worth 3 years after the question: Yes, your short proof is correct. The author of the long proof probably didn't have an important lemma at his disposal -- the fact that every tensor in $U \otimes U'$ can be written in the form $\sum_i f_i \otimes g_i$ for two linearly independent families $\left(f_i\right)_i$ and $\left(g_i\right)_i$.